# BackboneJS HelloWorld not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I tried running BackboneJS HelloWorld program, but I am getting a blank page.
Below is the program.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
 <title>Hello World in Backbone.js</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="JS/backbone.localStorage-min.js"></script>
<script src="JS/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="JS/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="JS/underscore-min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#container',
    initialize: function () {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html("Hello World");
    }
});

 var appView = new AppView();
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Note: Downloaded all the required libraries locally.

Link : http://adrianmejia.com/blog/2012/09/11/backbone-dot-js-for-absolute-beginners-getting-started/

Comment: open dev tools and check for possible error in console :)

Comment: Add console logs here

Comment: Change the order or your `<script>` tags, It needs to be => `jquery, backbone.min, backbone.localStorage-min.js` followed by `underscore.min.js` finally

Comment: is it important @DavidR when real code is used below all of this `<script>` impots?

Comment: @Andurit Yup, I have faced few issues similar to this, Furthermore having `backbone.localstorage` script inclusion before `backbone.min.js` doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @DavidR I rearranged the tags but still blank page

Comment: I am getting the bellow error in console:
    backbone-min.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property     'extend' of undefined
backbone.localStorage-min.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined
hello-backbone-js.html:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `Underscore` library's inclusion before including your `Backbone` library. Please rearrange the `<script>` inclusions given below.

```
<script src="JS/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="JS/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="JS/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="JS/backbone.localStorage-min.js"></script>
```

Also the you need to place html element with an id `container` because you're referring it in your `$el` attribute. Hence include the below `<div>` tag inside your `<body></body>` tags,

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Here is the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/du2b8vfv/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @David
I am still getting a blank page and in console getting the below error: 

    hello-backbone-js.html:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read     property 'extend' of undefined

I cannot even the access the given link for working fiddle. :(

Comment: May I know which version of `Backbone` you're using out there?. I've used `version 1.3.2` in my jsfiddle example.

Comment: I am using WebStorm as IDE. and backbone version is 0.9.2

Comment: Can you download Version `1.3.2` here - `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.2/backbone.js` and replace the current version (0.9.2) and then check if it is working or not?

Comment: Okay. Remove your existing backbone <script> tag and place this one and check, `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.2/backbone.js"></script>`

Comment: If i include this, I am getting many errors regarding "declaration not found", since backbone.js file is not available at given link.

Comment: I See. Can you atleast download this version from internet and try it if possible?

Comment: I downloaded  VERSION=1.3.3. Still same error on console

Comment: Clear your cache, cookies everything and try one more time?

Answer (score 0):

you are changing the value of el in render but not giving the value of el in html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Hello World in Backbone.js</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone-min.js"></script>

<div id="hh"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
AppView = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize: function () {

},
render: function () {
    this.$el.html("hello");
    return this;
}
});

var appView = new AppView();

$("#hh").html(appView.render().el);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```